Permission dialog: app wants to use confidential information
Permission Dialog
Whenever I use the Mailchimp app for macOS, I get a system dialog asking

Mailchimp wants to use your confidential information stored in Safari Forms autofill encryption key in your keychain


What I don't want
Mailchimp is the specific example here, but the same goes for most apps. I'd perfectly fine with Mailchimp retrieving its own password for mailchimp.com. What I DO NOT want is

Mailchimp to have access to any non-Mailchimp login information
Mailchimp to see what other accounts I have (e.g., to sell the information to data brokers)

Question
What is macOS really asking for with this dialog?

Permission for Mailchimp.app to access mailchimp.com login info
Permission for Mailchimp.app to access any login info
something else


Look in the key yourself.  What's there?  Then you will know.
